# delete Auto-Renewable subscription when user delete account

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap

I'm coding a mobile app (React Native) and using library react-native-iap to handle In-App Purchase logic for IOS device.

My question is: How to stop renew and delete current subscription when user delete their account?

I'm using Sandbox Tester on AppStoreConnect for In-App Purchase testing.

Comment: You can't. Only the user can cancel their subscription via their account settings

Comment: Hi @paulw11, that means if user doesn't cancel via iPhone setting and delete their account on **my application**, they will automatically continue paid for the subscription, right?

Comment: That is correct.  They will continue to be billed for the subscription until they cancel it, even though they can not access the benefits